# Cryptic Family Reunion: Current Events

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". **NOTE:** Unlike many previous puzzles in this genre, clues are NOT sorted alphabetically; however, lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Drunk jerk incarcerated, made bail, split for another Crown with Uncle (9)
2. Shriek about rotten tooth to grandma (5,2,6)
3. Cousin to peach furtively after smutty, odd rites ended badly (5,5,4,4,5)
4. Sister dancing the loopy twist, a tango (2'1,1,4,3,2,3,3)
5. Baby cosier unswaddled; after unleashing howl, lifting toy, grabbing ball (5,5,5)
6. Granddad's roll conceals $2,000 under a one (3,3)
7. Brother: "Over/under not moving, the bottom dropping out assumed for cellar-dweller" (13)
8. Nephew to slog awkwardly through grit, dirty and beat (5,3,6)
9. Dad's bar drinks, rum better around here (3,5,2,4)
10. Son in between two retreats supporting Healing Heart (4,2,5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are all:

> Song titles by the band **AC/DC** (hence the use of 'current' in the title!).

The answers and wordplay are as follows:

> 1. Drunk jerk incarcerated, made bail, split for another Crown with Uncle (9) **JAILBREAK** = JERK* around BAIL* and C(rown)
>
>  2. Shriek about rotten tooth to grandma (5,2,6) **SHOOT TO THRILL** = SHRILL ("shriek") around TOOTHTO*
>
>  3. Cousin to peach furtively after smutty, odd rites ended badly (5,5,4,4,5) **DIRTY DEEDS DONE DIRT CHEAP** = DIRTY ("smutty") + ODDRITESENDED* + PEACH*
>
>  4. Sister dancing the loopy twist, a tango (2'1,1,4,3,2,3,3) **IT’S A LONG WAY TO THE TOP** = THELOOPYTWISTATANGO*
>
>  5. Baby cosier unswaddled; after unleashing howl, lifting toy, grabbing ball (5,5,5) **WHOLE LOTTA ROSIE** = HOWL* + RATT(O)LE< ("toy" with 'o' for "ball") + (-c)OSIE(-r)
>
>  6. Granddad's roll conceals \$2,000 under a one (3,3) **BIG GUN** = BUN ("roll") around I ("one") + GG (\$1000 is a 'G')
>
>  7. Brother: "Over/under not moving, the bottom dropping out assumed for cellar-dweller" (13) **THUNDERSTRUCK** = TH(e) + UNDER + STUCK ("not moving") around (fo)R (R is the 'cellar-dweller' i.e. 'bottom letter' of the word 'FOR')
>
>  8. Nephew to slog awkwardly through grit, dirty and beat (5,3,6) **GIRLS GOT RHYTHM** = GRIT* around SLOG* + RHYTHM ("beat")
>
>  9. Dad's bar drinks, rum better around here (3,5,2,4) **LET THERE BE ROCK** = LOCK ("bar") around BETTER* around HERE
>
>  10. Son in between two retreats supporting Healing Heart (4,2,5) **BACK IN BLACK** = BACK ("retreat") + IN + BACK ("retreat") around (hea)L(ing)

Comment: Rock on! All the answers are right. The wordplay on the one you're missing is a bit twisty. The good thing about this topic is rot13(nyzbfg rirel fbat unf qvegl be ebpx va vg, fb V pbhyq gel gb uvqr nantenzf!)

Comment: re: edit...how is rot13("nffhzrq sbe pryyne-qjryyre") used? I'm not the best at cluing, but that would be way too many extra words even for me!

Comment: My intention on #7 was to rot13(trg gur E sebz gur "pryyne-qjryyre" bs "sbe", fb nf abg gb unir "sbe" or rkgenarbhf). Does that make sense to you as a solver?

Comment: @JeremyDover Ah, okay - I see that now - will amend...

Answer (score 5):

These are:

> Songs by the Australian rock band AC/DC

1. Drunk jerk incarcerated, made bail, split for another Crown with Uncle (9)

> JAILBREAK = JERK + BAIL + A (the crown/1st letter of "another")

2. Shriek about rotten tooth to grandma (5,2,6)

> SHOOT TO THRILL = SHRILL about TOOTH TO

3. Cousin to peach furtively after smutty, odd rites ended badly (5,5,4,4,5)

> DIRTY DEEDS DONE DIRT CHEAP = DIRTY (smutty) + ODD RITES ENDED + PEACH

4. Sister dancing the loopy twist, a tango (2'1,1,4,3,2,3,3)

> IT'S A LONG WAY TO THE TOP = THE LOOPY TWIST A TANGO

5. Baby cosier unswaddled; after unleashing howl, lifting toy, grabbing ball (5,5,5)

> WHOLE LOTTA ROSIE = OSIE (cosier-cr) after WHOL (howl unleashed), RATTLE inverted, grabbing O

6. Granddad's roll conceals $2,000 under a one (3,3)

> BIG GUN = BUN (roll) conceals GG under I

7. Brother: "Over/under not moving, the bottom dropping out assumed for cellar-dweller" (13)

> THUNDERSTRUCK = UNDER + STUCK (not moving) + TH ("the" bottom dropping out) + R (cellar of dweller)

8. Nephew to slog awkwardly through grit, dirty and beat (5,3,6)

> GIRLS GOT RHYTHM = SLOG + GRIT, + RHYTHM (beat)

9. Dad's bar drinks, rum better around here (3,5,2,4)

> LET THERE BE ROCK = LOCK (bar) "drinks" (encloses) BETTER around HERE

10. Son in between two retreats supporting Healing Heart (4,2,5)

> BACK IN BLACK = IN between two retreats = BACK IN BACK + heart of "HEALING"

Comment: Well done! Except rot13(gur onaq vf gur cevqr bs Nhfgenyvn, abg Nzrevpn)!

Comment: Dude! How did I NOT KNOW THAT?!